# Optimize long chain of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a Customer that goes to the Shop which has a Manager. Both Customer and Manager are from People model, different roles only.

What is the best way to get a Manager from Customer?

Right now I have this solution which is very slow:

```
shop_manager = customer.shop.people.select{|p| p.has_role?(:manager)}.first
```

**person.rb:**

```
belongs_to :shop
```

**shop.rb:**

```
has_many :people
```

Roles are assigned using [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem.

Comment: show us the associations for `person`, `shop`, also how you storing `roles`

Comment: Please see updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
shop_manager = customer.shop.people.with_role(:manger).first
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Any other possibilities to make it run faster?

Comment: I'm not sure how the `with_role` method works in the background, but that's included in the documentation, I suppose it should be efficient? do `customer.shop.people.with_role(:manger).to_sql` in your rails console, and post the result here, and I will take a look at the sql side